# Why is Arguments.callee.caller null?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

A few days back I was testing my application on google chrome 40 version. I have a client side error logging system which generates the stack trace by looping over the argument.callee. By doing is I generate the stack trace.

```
stackTrace = function(){
    var currFunc = arguments.callee;
    var j =0;
    var listTrace =[], fn;
    while (currFunc && listTrace.length < 20) {
            //Limit stack track to 20 functions
            fn = currFunc.toString();
            listTrace[j++] = fn;
            currFunc = currFunc.caller;
    }
    return listTrace;
};
```

Only today did I update my chrome to 44 version and now the problem is I am not able to get the stack trace. I debugged to find out the reason and saw that the argument.callee.caller is null. I am not sure why but I read that JS bound function can cause this. No idea though. How do I solve this ? Is there any alternate way to get the caller ?

Comment: Have you considered using the (admittedly non-standard) `stack` property of Error instances?

Comment: I am trying to catch the uncaught exception so basically not using the try catch

Comment: @rk8785: Which "uncaught exception"?

Comment: @rk8785 the Error object doesn't necessarily have anything to do with `try ... catch` - you can create a new Error object and get the `stack` property any time you want.

Comment: any uncaught exceptions that might occur in the application. So when the error occurs it goes to window.onError which I have modified and I try to generate a stack trace over there